# Skype message causes loud noise

Tags: skype

Skype is causing a loud buzzing noise whenever I send a message that continues even after I close out of it. After a short time period the noise will change to a different sound but I'm not sure what is causing it.

I looked for `load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=... tsched=...` but couldn't find `use_ucm=... tsched=...` in said line.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with awful noise after sending a message in Skype 4.2.0.11 on Ubuntu 13.10. I was able to solve it by editing /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop and updating the exec command to:

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with Skype sounds but don't know if that solution will work for you.

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

There is a line

```
“load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=... tsched=..."
```

Set

```
tsched=0
```